# generating a valid password - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following method to generate random passwords:

```
char_set = {
'small': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
'nums': '0123456789',
'big': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
'special': '^!\$%&/()=?{[]}+~#-_.:,;<>|\\'
}

def gen_password(length=21):
    '''
    Generate a random password containing upper and lower case letters,
    numbers and special characters.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    The default length is 21 chars, however the minimum is 8 chars.

    Returns:
    --------
    str: The random password
    '''
    assert length >= 8
    password = []

    while len(password) < length:
        key = random.choice(char_set.keys())
        a_char = os.urandom(1)
        if a_char in char_set[key]:
            if check_prev_char(password, char_set[key]):
                continue
            else:
                password.append(a_char)
    return ''.join(password)

def check_prev_char(password, current_char_set):
    '''
    Ensure that there are not consecutive Uppercase / Lowecase / Number / special
    characters in the password.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    password: (str)
        The candidate password
    current_char_set: (char)
        The current character to be compared.

    Returns:
    --------
    Bool: if the candidate password is good so far.
    '''

    index = len(password)
    if index == 0:
        return False
    else:
        prev_char = password[index - 1]
        if prev_char in current_char_set:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Although it works in most cases, there are a few cases it fails, for example, when the password has a `\` or doesn't have a number.
How can I ensure all the passwords I'm generating doesn't contain `\` and also always contain at least a number?

Comment: If you don't want \ then remove it from your initial character set (it's the last member of `char_set['special']`). `check_prev_char` could be tremendously simplified because Python already supports negative indexing, so `s[-1]` is the last character of `s`. If `s` is empty this throws `IndexError` which you can catch.

Comment: I'm not sure what the security implications of doing it this way are, but I'm not sure you're not better off concatenating at least bits of the parts you want (some numbers, some of each kind of letter, some special chars) and shuffling to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `\` in your password, remove them from the special charset (is there a reason it's there?):

```
'special': '^!\$%&/()=?{[]}+~#-_.:,;<>|'
```

To ensure it always has a number, generate a password with `n-1` characters and then add a number at a random position:

```
def gen_final_password(length=21):
    password = gen_password(length - 1)
    index = random.randint(0, length)
    number = random.choice(char_set['nums'])
    return password[:index] + number + password[index:]
```

But please note this may not generate a cryptographically random password, with the full expected entropy. For that you would need to always use a crypto-random source and use all characters with equal likelihood. Right now the algorithm prefers characters from small charsets (e.g. it's more likely to include a `0` than `a`). Also, avoiding consecutive characters of the same charset has unknown, bad implications to entropy.

Finally, `check_prev_char` can be simplified to the expression:

```
len(password) and password[-1] in char_set[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*\\)(?=.*\d).*$
```

You can do a `re.match` at the end to make sure `password` does not have `/` and has at least one `\d`.

Comment: I want to generate the password that always fulfill those requirements.

Comment: @philippe You can call `gen_password()` recursively if it doesn't meet the given requirements

Comment: Also, `0Uo(Y\O:3Cy~1S#Pr!x7S` doesn't match ... `re.match` returns `None`

Comment: @philippe why should it match...it has `\\` in it

Comment: @vks Sorry I didn't pay attention

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the password you generate to contain '\', why not just remove that character from the defined char_set you obtain characters for the password from?

As for generating the passwords that always have at least one number, you could check the generated password for a number before returning it and overwrite a random character with a random number before returning the password if a number is needed.